# How can I execute a base64 encoded exe stored as a variable, inside a powershell script without writing any files?

Tags: encryption, injection, powershell

Basically if I have exe1 encoded with base64 and I copy that encoded source into a powershell script as a variable. I want to be able to decode it and execute the source exe without writing the exe to disk. is this possible? if so how can it be done.

Comment: This feels like an X-Y problem. What issue are you trying to solve by converting a .exe into base64 and trying to launch it from a powershell script?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that you're not going to be able to. Unless you have a library that can load a PE32 into memory correctly, which is not the same thing as allocating a single, continguous block of memory and copying the bytes into it, then you're going to have to write the binary to disk and rely on Windows to load it for you.